# Setting up outgoing mail on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, sendmail, email

I am setting up a VPS on linode but I can't seem to setup a mail sending program like sendmail so that I can send emails through PHP.

I am stuck at the very first step of changing the hostname. I changed the entries under `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` but when I even reboot the VPS, then `hostname -f` shows `hostname: Name or service not known`

What's wrong? And any good tutorial for setting things up?

I am using nginx, if that somehow matters in any case.

Content of `/etc/hosts`

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
178.79.162.174 mail.bankpo.in

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Content of `/etc/hostname`

```
mail.bankpo.in
```

And `which hostname` returns `/bin/hostname`

Comment: What did you put in /etc/hosts?

Comment: What does it tell you when you do ´which hostname´ ?

Comment: @TiZon @Matthieu I have added the info in the question, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1       mail.bankpo.in      mail localhost
178.79.162.174       mail.bankpo.in      mail
```

add this to `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
domain bankpo.in
search bankpo.in
```

Then, reboot and try with `/bin/hostname --fqdn`

To set-up email, this is what I would do:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get update -y
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install postfix mailutils -y
sudo postconf -e "mydestination = mail.bankpo.in, bankpo.in, localhost.localdomain, localhost"
sudo postconf -e "mynetworks = 0.0.0.0/32"
sudo postconf -e "inet_interfaces = all"
sudo  /etc/init.d/postfix restart
```

Comment: @TiZon Thanks! That did it. Any pointers for a simple tutorial for setting things up so that I can send mail. Which one do you suggest out of `sendmail` and others?

Comment: @Ashfame I have edited my answer with some installation-instructions. I would go with `sendmail`.

Comment: @TiZon Thanks a lot so far! I think its almost ready. I managed to get to the same point using exim and your instructions (tried yours afterwards, after removing exim). If I send a test mail using `echo "This is a test." | mail -s Testing someone@somedomain.com`, I get the email, but if I use PHP mail function, it return boolean false. Do I need to make changes in some PHP config file too? Or that should be a different question possibly out of scope of serverfault?

Comment: I think PHP uses `sendmail`, Can you send an email via sendmail?

Comment: @TiZon Yeah! I can. I tried using the code on this page http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=465

Comment: Sorry, no expert on PHP-config. Try researching your php.ini... But other than that, I wouldn't know.